# How to launch Django development server with a different database setting (not default)

Tags: python, database, django, settings, local

i have different configurations for django database in settings, one named "default" and one named "clean".

How i can run the development server (`python manage.py runserver ip:port`) binding the "clean" database setting and not the default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hold 2 different settings.py and while run manage.py do :
python manage.py runserver --settings=[projectname].[settingsfile].

change the settingsfile according to your database.

Comment: thank you, i've missed that in the docs (maybe it's not there?)

i've created another file settings who copies the standard default settings and changes the database

Answer (score 3):

```
if DEBUG:
    DATABASES = {
        'clean': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.',
            'NAME': '',
            'USER': '',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': '',
            'PORT': '',
            },
        }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.',
            'NAME': '',
            'USER': '',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': '',
            'PORT': '',
            },
        }
```

Comment: i dont like this because even if it's correct i have to load different databases for different purposes when DEBUG is True, so it's not enough

Comment: You should never use debug in a live environment, the server email setting is for that purpose

Comment: i have different databases in local environment, one to create fixture for test, the other for development. that's why it's not enough. of course in live envinronment DEBUG is False!